# How to work around the lack of abstract classes in rust?

Tags: rust, abstract

Let's say I have common logic that depends intimately on data members as well as a piece of abstract logic. How can I write this in rust types without rewriting the same code for each implementation?

Here's a toy example of what I might write in scala. Note that the abstract class has concrete logic that depends on both the data member `name` and abstract logic `formatDate()`.

```scala
abstract class Greeting(name: String) {
  def greet(): Unit = {
    println(s"Hello $name\nToday is ${formatDate()}.")
  }

  def formatDate(): String
}

class UsaGreeting(name: String) extends Greeting {
  override def formatDate(): String = {
    // somehow get year, month, day
    s"$month/$day/$year"
  }
}

class UkGreeting(name: String) extends Greeting {
  override def formatDate(): String = {
    // somehow get year, month, day
    s"$day/$month/$year"
  }
}
```

This is just a toy example, but my real life constraints are:

- I have several data members - not just one (`name`).
- Every subclass has the same complex methods that depends on both those data members and abstract functions specific to the subclass.
- For good API design, it's important the implementing `struct`s continue to hold all those data members and complex methods.

Here are some somewhat unsatisfactory ideas I had that could make this work in rust:

- I could require a `get_name()` method on the trait that every implementation would need. But this seems unnecessarily verbose and might also cause a performance hit if the getter doesn't get inlined.
- I could avoid using a rust trait altogether, instead making a struct with an additional data member that implements the missing abstract logic. But this makes the abstract logic unavailable at compile time, and would definitely cause a performance hit.
- I could again avoid using a rust trait altogether, instead making a struct with a generic whose associated functions complete the abstract logic. So far this is my best idea, but it feels wrong to use generics to fill in missing logic.

I'm not fully happy with these ideas, so is there a better way in rust to mix abstract logic with concrete logic that depends on data members?

Comment: Any particular reason why the `Greeting` keeps the name itself? Why not `def greet(name: String)`?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question because it's both, at parts, very wide and vague (you can't answer about the general no OO design in just a SO answer) and then exhibits a specific case which can receive a focused answer.

Comment: I voted "needs focus" but I'm never really sure what to do with these software architecture questions that are abstract in nature. **You cannot divorce the design of a program from the problem it solves.** If your goal is to format different kinds of greetings there are probably a hundred ways to write a program that does that which would make more sense than this. But you are just using `Greeting` as an example - it is pure structure, with no requirements or constraints - so it's impossible to make an informed recommendation.

Comment: @kmdreko Yes. As this is a toy example, I see that it would be tempting to pull `name` out in some way, but in my actual project, there is intricate concrete logic accessing both the data members and abstract functions many times, so they can't really be separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most general solution seems to be my original 3rd bullet: instead of a trait, make a struct with a generic whose associated functions complete the functionality.

For the original toy `Greeting` example Denys's answer is probably best. But a more general solution that addresses main question is:

```
trait Locale {
  pub fn format_date() -> String;
}

pub struct Greeting<LOCALE: Locale> {
  name: String,
  locale: PhantomData<LOCALE>, // needed to satisfy compiler
}

impl<LOCALE: Locale> Greeting<LOCALE> {
  pub fn new(name: String) {
    Self {
      name,
      locale: PhantomData,
    }
  }

  pub fn greet() {
    format!("Hello {}\nToday is {}", self.name, LOCALE::format_date());
  }
}

pub struct UsaLocale;

impl Locale for UsaLocale {
  pub fn format_date() -> {
    // somehow get year, month, day
    format!("{}/{}/{}", month, day, year)
  };
}

pub type UsaGreeting = Greeting<UsaLocale>;
pub type UkGreeting = ...
```

Answer (score 9):

As you noticed, Rust isn't built around a class taxonomy principle, so the design is usually different and you should not try to mock OO languages in Rust.

You ask a very general question but there are a lot of specific cases calling for different solutions.

Very often when you're tempted in a OO language to define what objects are with classes, you'd use traits to specify some aspects of the behaviors of structs in Rust.

In your specific case, assuming the right solution shouldn't involve parameterization or a i18n utility, I'd probably use both composition and an enum for the way to greet:

```rust
pub struct Greeting {
    name: String,
    greeter: Greeter;
}
impl Greeting {
    pub fn greet(&self) -> String {
        // use self.greeter.date_format() and self.name
    }
}

pub enum Greeter {
    USA,
    UK,
}
impl Greeter {
    fn date_format(&self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
           USA => ...,
           UK => ...,
        }
    }    
}
```

Your composite implementation just has to switch on the variant when needed.

*(note that I don't write the implementation in this case because perf concerns would probably call in Rust for a different design and not a dynamically interpreted pattern, but that would bring us far from your question)*

Comment: But where would dependence on data members like `name` come in? I don't think there's a way to require that each enum value has a `name: String`, is there?

Comment: @mwlon You're right I totally overlooked that part of your question's code. I've updated the answer. Of course you could add the name to each variant but it would be cumbersome and would mix concerns so composition seems more in order here.

Comment: As for every design question, the real solution is highly dependent of the *real* problem and is most often also tied to personal preferences. I try to get leads, or hints, but not the final design.

Answer (score 1):

You can add function that will return references to required fields and define default implementation for function. It is common technique in java or C# (`get; set;`)

```rust
trait Greeting: 
{
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
    fn format_date(&self) -> &str;
    fn greet(&self)
    {
        println!("Hello {}\n Today is {}", self.get_name(), self.format_date());
    }
}

struct USAGreeting{name: String }
struct UKGreeting{name: String }

impl Greeting for USAGreeting
{
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str { &self.name }

    fn format_date(&self) -> &str {
        return "$month/$day/$year"
    }
}

impl Greeting for UKGreeting
{
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str { &self.name }

    fn format_date(&self) -> &str {
        return "$day/$month/$year"
    }
}

fn main() {
    let uk = UKGreeting { name: "UK Greeting!".to_owned() };
    let usa = UKGreeting { name: "UK Greeting!".to_owned() };

    let dynamic: Vec<&dyn Greeting> = vec![&uk, &usa];

    for greeter in dynamic
    {
        greeter.get_name();
        greeter.greet();
    }
}
```

Now `Greeting` is usable in dynamic or generic context. Ofc you have to define `get_name() -> &str` every time you implement `Greeting`. So workaround could look like this:

```rust
trait Named
{
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
}

trait Greeting: Named 
{
    fn format_date(&self) -> &str;
    fn greet(&self)
    {
        println!("Hello {}\n Today is {}", self.get_name(), self.format_date());
    }
}

impl Greeting for USAGreeting
{
    fn format_date(&self) -> &str {
        return "$month/$day/$year"
    }
}

impl Greeting for UKGreeting
{
    fn format_date(&self) -> &str {
        return "$day/$month/$year"
    }
}
```

It does not solve the problem but seperates it form `Greeting` trait. now you can use procedural macros (`#[derive()]`) to generate `get_name` automaticly.

For example procedural macro could look like this

```rust
use proc_macro::{self, TokenStream};
use quote::quote;
use syn;

#[proc_macro_derive(NamedMacro)]
pub fn describe(tokens: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast: syn::DeriveInput = syn::parse(tokens).unwrap();

    let name = &ast.ident;

    quote! {
        impl Named for #name {
            fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
               &self.name
            }
        }
    }.into()

}
```

And then adding `get_name()` to struct is easy:

```
use my_macro::NamedMacro;

#[derive(NamedMacro)]
struct USAGreeting{ name: String }
#[derive(NamedMacro)]
struct UKGreeting{ name: String }
```

You can read about macros here

[Procedural Macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html)

[Macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html)